# how to let eclipse show package together in macbook?

Tags: eclipse

I import `commons-collection4` project into elipse, show package that stype:

[image]

but my else project show that:

[image]

I want to show like `commons-collection4` style, what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that `org.apache.commons.collections4` is not the name of a folder on disk?

Comment: yes, i'm sure  !

Answer (score 0):

In ***Window > Preferences: Java > Appearance*** check the checkbox ***Fold empty packages in hierarchical layout in Package and Project Explorer***.